# SQL case condition with error failed converting

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query that causes this error:

> Failed when converting the varchar value ')' to data type tinyint.

This is my code in question:

```
select  
    case t.name 
       when 'numeric' 
          then cast (c.precision + ')' as varchar(100)) 
    end 
from 
    sys.columns c 
inner join 
    sys.types t ON t.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
inner join 
    sys.tables tb on tb.name = 'EX_EMPLOYEE' 
where  
    c.name = 'B_CODE' and tb.object_id = c.object_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps (if 2012+)

```
case t.name when 'numeric' then concat(c.precision,')') end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
select  
     case t.name when 'numeric' then cast (c.precision as varchar(100)) +')' end
```

as `c.precision` is obviously a `tinyint` data type. It fails on `c.precision +')'` as you're adding different data types.

Answer (score 1):

Move your concatenation to outside the `CAST`, also changed `JOIN` and `WHERE` parameters around.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN t.name = 'numeric' 
            THEN CAST(c.precision AS varchar(100)) +')'
       END
FROM sys.columns c 
INNER JOIN sys.types t ON t.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
INNER JOIN sys.tables tb ON tb.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE c.name = 'B_CODE'
AND tb.name = 'EX_EMPLOYEE'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to cast the tinyint value to a varchar before concatenating them. Like this (or just cast the c.precision as varchar(100) and then add the ')':

```
    select  
    case t.name when 'numeric' then cast (cast (c.precision as varchar(10)) +')' as varchar(100)) 
    end 

    from sys.columns c inner JOIN sys.types t ON t.user_type_id = 
    c.user_type_id
    inner join sys.tables tb on tb.name='EX_EMPLOYEE' where  c.name = 
    'B_CODE' and tb.object_id = c.object_id
```